# Define a globally available bash function to be used by any script

Tags: server, bash

I'm running a simple webserver using Ubuntu server. I would like to use a simple function that will post a message to slack using webhooks such as [this one](http://blog.pragbits.com/it/2015/02/09/slack-notifications-via-curl/).

Where should I put this function such that it can be called by any user on the system (e.g. www-data)? Currently I `source` it from my `.bashrc` file which allows me to use it but I have not tested with other users.

The idea is to get something like fail2ban to post a slack message when it bans a user, for example, but that's another question altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the definition in a file with extension `.sh` in `/etc/profile.d`.

Do `man bash` for details.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to work, even after logging in/out. Do I need to `source` `etc/profile` for it to kick in?

Comment: No. Unless your system is completely non-standard (or decades of "tradition" has been broken), the sourcing of `/etc/profile` is automatic for all kinds of shells. So, can you be more precise about what is not working: the script file is not sourced vs the definition doesn't happen vs the function doesn't work?

Comment: It's a bog standard ubuntu 14.04 server. I actually run zsh as my shell over ssh but when I try the function I get `zsh: command not found: post_to_slack`. If I `source /etc/profile.d/post_to_slack.sh` it then works. Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: Right. I use zsh too. Section 5.1 of `info zsh` (from `zsh-doc`) reminded me that the tradition is indeed broken by zsh: non-interactive shells only source `/etc/zshenv`, if there is one.

Comment: OK, thanks, I actually ended up porting to a ruby script instead so I can just reference the script directly. E.g. `ruby /home/me/send_to_slack.rb "Hello World"`