# Bash: Define a function in bashrc that can be used by any scripts globally

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc, functions

I like to define a function in `~/.bashrc` and use it in different scripts either via `export -f` or `source .bashrc`.

The function:

```
nano ~/.bashrc

function test_func() {
    yt-dlp -f '299+140' --merge-output-format mp4 -cia List.txt;
}

export -f test_func
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/admn/Downloads/YT_DL;

test_func --autonumber-start 101 -o '%(autonumber)1d_%(title)s.%(ext)s';
```

Problem-1:

After `test_func`, rest of the command `--autonumber-start 101 -o '%(autonumber)1d_%(title)s.%(ext)s'` is not working at all.

---

---

Problem-2:

Earlier when I tried to use `source .bashrc` in my script, I was getting these errors:

```
/usr/local/scripts/test.sh: line 3: .bashrc: No such file or directory
/usr/local/scripts/test.sh: line 12: test_func: command not found
```

The function (without `export -f`):

```
nano ~/.bashrc

function test_func() {
    yt-dlp -f '299+140' --merge-output-format mp4 -cia List.txt;
}
```

The script (with `source .bashrc`):

```
#!/bin/bash

source .bashrc

cd /home/admn/Downloads/YT_DL;

test_func --autonumber-start 101 -o '%(autonumber)1d_%(title)s.%(ext)s';
```

**Edit-1**:

```
$ bash -xv /usr/local/scripts/test.sh
#!/bin/bash

source /home/admn/.bashrc
+ source /home/admn/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# alias pip='pip3.7'
alias python='python3'
++ alias python=python3

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
++ case $- in
++ return

test_func --autonumber-start 101 -o '%(autonumber)1d_%(title)s.%(ext)s';
+ test_func --autonumber-start 101 -o '%(autonumber)1d_%(title)s.%(ext)s'
/usr/local/scripts/test.sh: line 5: test_func: command not found
$
```

These are some of the threads I have gone through; and though I've got some ideas, I still couldn't work out a solution for my use case. Thanks.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63665/how-to-define-a-bash-function-that-can-be-used-by-different-scripts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218268/how-to-define-a-bash-function-for-use-in-any-script

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219174/variables-set-in-bashrc-and-accessing-them-in-shellscript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500499/how-do-you-call-a-function-defined-in-bashrc-from-the-shell

[Define a globally available bash function to be used by any script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707685/define-a-globally-available-bash-function-to-be-used-by-any-script)

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

Bash: 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the function to use parameters, you need to explicitly mention them.

```bsh
function test_func() {
    yt-dlp "$@" -f '299+140' --merge-output-format mp4 -cia List.txt
    #      ~~~~
}
```

`"$@"` stands for "all the parameters", you can also use positional parameters like `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc.

If you source a file from a different directory, you need to either specify a full path to it, or have the file's path in `$PATH`.

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc
# or
PATH+=:~
source .bashrc
```

**After the update:**
Your `.bashrc` contains a `return` that stops processing the `.bashrc` if not running in an interactive shell. Put the function declaration somewhere before the condition if you want to execute it in non-interactive shells, too.

Comment: Try running your scripts under `set -xv` so you see what commands are being run.

Comment: The `return` exits the `.bashrc` before it gets to the function declaration.

Comment: Your `.bashrc` contains `return` that stops processing the `.bashrc` if not running in an interactive shell. Put the function declaration somewhere before the condition if you want to execute it in non-interactive shells, too.

Comment: posting function before `return` condition solved it. So, does this part `# If not running interactively, don't do anything | case $- in | *i*) ;; | *) return;; | esac` needs to go at the end of `.bashrc` file? Thank you so much.

Comment: Lastly, is there a "preferred / standard / better" way to call function from `.bashrc`? I mean, `export -f` vs `source ~/.bashrc` Thanks

Comment: The "return" part should go before the stuff you want in an interactive shell, but don't want in a non-interactive one.

Comment: I'm no expert but I prefer `source` to `export`.

Comment: That's what I read in few places too that `source` is preferred/better way. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can 'run' your script file by sourcing it. Let's say you have defined your custom script with functions in `./myScript`. Then in the beginning of each script where you want to use these functions, you source this file:

```
# Load my custom functions from file
source ./myScript
```

This is extremely common programming practice, and doing it this way will prevent unneeded aliases and functions from being added to `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`).

Comment: This is indeed my preferred way to do it. 